# How to allow user to only select one background image with color change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a form to select one of the image. So i need to select only one image but it should also change its backgtound color on hover:
[image: I am making a form to select one of the image. So i need to select only one image but it should also change its backgtound color on hover]

```js
   let changeBg = document.querySelectorAll(".arch");
        changeBg.forEach((i) => {
            i.addEventListener("click", () => {
                [...changeBg].map((el) => (el.style.cssText = " background: #DDDDDD;"));
                i.style.cssText = " background: #F7D8BA;";
            });
        });
```

```html
   <div class="footArchBox">
                        <img class="arch footarch" src="./assets/flat.svg" alt="">
                        <img class="arch footarch" src="./assets/normal.svg" alt="">
                        <img class="arch footarch" src="./assets/high.svg" alt="">
                    </div>
```

Comment: Don't post images, especially not of unnecessary stuff like in this case. If you don't do anything with the return value of `.map()` then `.map()` is the wrong tool. The return value of `.querySelectorAll()`, a `NodeList` has a `.forEach()` method that you already use. So why the `[...changeBg].map(...)`? Why do you overwrite the complete `.style` content via `.cssText` when you only want to change the background? And why `background` and not just `backgroundColor`? If you only want to allow one item to be selected then use a radio button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `classList` with `remove()` and `toggle()` for this

```js
const changeBg = document.querySelectorAll(".arch");

changeBg.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", () => {
  changeBg.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'))
  el.classList.toggle('active')
}));
```

```css
.arch {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
}

.active {
  border-color: #F7D8BA;
}
```

```html
<div class="footArchBox">
  <img class="arch footarch" src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="">
  <img class="arch footarch" src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="">
  <img class="arch footarch" src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add the listener on the parent and then use `target` to extract the element that was actually clicked on:

```js
const box = document.getElementById("footArchBox");

let currentlySelected;

box.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  // Remove the class from the previously selected element
  if (currentlySelected) {
    currentlySelected.classList.remove("selected");
  }
  
  currentlySelected = event.target;
  
  currentlySelected.classList.add("selected");
});
```

```css
.arch:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.arch.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="footArchBox">
  <img width="100" class="arch footarch" src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/se/se-icon.svg" alt="">
  <img width="100" class="arch footarch" src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/se/se-icon.svg" alt="">
  <img width="100" class="arch footarch" src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/se/se-icon.svg" alt="">
</div>
```

Feel free to get back to me in the comments if something isn't clear.

*also, please put more effort into styling than me lol*